# Sublime Text selection using Lua/love2d

Tags: lua, sublimetext2, sublimetext, love2d

say i have this line of code :

```
Object.Property.field;
Object.Property:FunctionName();
```

in all my sublime languages if i was to double click "Property" on either line, it would select just that word.
For some reason my lua/lua love2d syntax highlighting selects the whole line up to the ":"

How can I change this behavior, so it will only select the single word?

Comment: What syntax are you using? Is it the default `Lua` that comes with Sublime, or did you install a plugin? If you did install a plugin, what is its name and URL?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is occurring is because of a somewhat strange addition to the [`Lua Love`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Lua%20Love) plugin, which I assume you're using. You're using Sublime 2, so select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up your `Packages` folder, then open the `Lua Love` subfolder. There is a file called `completions.py`, which has this content:

```py
#completions.py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class LoveCompletions(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    ST = 3000 if sublime.version() == '' else int(sublime.version())

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if self.ST < 3000 and ("lua" in view.scope_name(locations[0])):
            seps = view.settings().get("word_separators")
            seps = seps.replace('.', '')
            view.settings().set("word_separators", seps)
```

Even if you don't know Python, the logic is pretty easy to follow. It sets the variable `ST` to Sublime's version, which is 3000+ if you're using ST3 (current build is 3061), and is 2221 (I think) for ST2. It then sets up an event listener (the process is always running in the background) checking to see if the Sublime version is less than 3000 (you're using ST2) and you have `lua` in your current scope (basically, your file is `source.lua` or `source.lua.love`, if you're using the plugin's language definition). If both of those are true, it removes the `.` character from your `"word_separators"` setting, which is defined in **`Preferences -> Settings-Default`** and can be overridden in **`Preferences -> Settings-User`**.

The `word_separators` setting controls what characters are considered to be word separators when double-clicking to select a word. Its default value is `` ./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~? `` so, for example, if you double-click on the `foo` part of `foo-bar` Sublime will only select `foo`, but if you double-click on the `foo` part of `foo_bar` Sublime will select the whole thing (since `-` is in `word_separators`). `.` is in `word_separators` by default, so double-clicking on `foo` in `foo.bar` will only select `foo`, which is expected behavior for most people, I would assume. However, this cute little plugin removes `.` from `word_separators` in Sublime Text 2, so in your case clicking on `Property` selects everything from the beginning of the "word" (the whitespace before `Object`) to the next word separator - the `:`, in the case of your second example.

OK, so we know what the problem is, how do we fix it? First, while you're in `Packages/Lua Love`, just delete `completions.py` altogether. There's no harm in doing so, and in fact it's actually *causing* harm by being there. Make sure you restart Sublime after deleting the file. Next, open **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add `.` back into the `word_separators` list, anywhere between the beginning and ending double-quotes. Save that file, go back to your source code, and double-clicking should once again behave normally.

Good luck!

---

***EDIT***

I submitted this [pull request](https://github.com/szensk/subllualove/pull/5) to delete the `completions.py` file from the plugin's Github repo, and it was just merged, so hopefully users in the future won't have to deal with this :)

Comment: wow ! +1 information, +1 for solution, +1 for request
no notes for you today

however ! my Preferences-settings-user has no "word_separators" 
should it do ?

Comment: @user3700360 if `word_separators` isn't in there, don't worry about it. Just delete `Packages/Lua Love/completions.py`, restart Sublime, and you should be all set.